# Jenkins agent goes offline or down often

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-build-flow

We have an automation job set up in Jenkins with Agent/node. But the job goes to queue sometimes because agent is offline or down. One of us have to login to the remote server machine/agent/node to make it online by running the slave in cmd and it gets connected.

Is there a way to keep it online always or checking for the agent is online during build job trigger? Any way using shell script or bat file to make this possible ?

Answers are appreciated. Thanks!

We make it connected manually by login in to the agent

Comment: did you managed to solve this problem?

Comment: No Dev, Not yet resolved. Any help is appreciated.